# Make texcount ignore appendices

Tags: appendices, texcount

Is it possible to tell `texcount` to stop counting when it reaches appendices? (i.e. the `\appendix` command)?

I'm using `texcount`. to check my thesis which is organised so that each chapter has its own `\input{blah.tex}`.
I need the count **excluding** appendices and biblography but **including** footnotes and captions.

Now I think most of this is done by `texcount` by default (please correct my if I'm wrong) except for the appendices part. Can't figure out an option to tell texcount to stop. I wonder if it's possible to drop some kind of comment into the document or if there is an option that I have overlooked.

I can, of course do the adding up by hand. But that feels a little clunky.

Comment: `%TC:ignore                ignore region, end with %TC:endignore` ... from the texcount help

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yep. I'm an idiot. I read the help... just not very well evidentially.

Comment: Well, it's a little bit hidden, at least in the console help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just enclose the region not to be counted (the appendix stuff here) with `%TC:ignore` and `%TC:endignore`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

And now for something completely different

%TC:ignore 
\appendix
And now for something completely different
%TC:endignore 
\end{document}
```

This should give:

```
File: texcountexample.tex
Encoding: ascii
Words in text: 6
Words in headers: 0
Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
Number of headers: 0
Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
Number of math inlines: 0
Number of math displayed: 0
```